# Error: CORS error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource SvelteKit

Tags: node.js, express, cors, sveltekit

I have 2 folder, one called "backEnd" and another is "frontEnd"

structure:

```
|-backEnd
|--app.js
|-frontEnd
|--src
|---routes
|---- +page.svelte
|---- +page.js
```

backEnd I use nodejs with express, here is the code

```
let express = require("express")
let app = express()
let PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000


app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
    res.json({message: "Hello World"})
})


app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

The frontEnd I use sveltekit with vite
Here is the code in "+page.js"

```
export let load = async ({ fetch }) => {
    let rawRes = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/")
    let data = await rawRes.json()

    return {data: data}
}
```

And here is the code in "page.svelte"

```
<script>
    export let data
    console.log(data)
</script>
<div>
    Hello
</div>
```

When I run "npm run dev" I get the error
"Error: CORS error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

How can I fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) middleware to enable [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) for the server.

E.g.

```js
let express = require("express")
let cors = require('cors')
let app = express()
let PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.use(cors())

app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
    res.json({message: "Hello World"})
})


app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`)
})
```